# Always keep footer under content

Tags: html, css

The footer in my webpage always sticks to the bottom of the page covering content instead of always staying right after the content of my page. I am using absolute position on it but it just goes the spot that is the bottom of the viewport when the page is at the top and stays there so it can be scrolled past.

```css
.footer{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<div class='footer'>FOOTER</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `body`'s `position` `relative` or you can create a relatively positioned wrapper `div` for the `footer` with `height: 100%` to up the entire height of the document. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) states that:

> The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor (i.e., the nearest ancestor that is not static).

This means that the `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom` properties are applied to the element relative to the closest ancestor that is not statically positioned. If its parent is relatively positioned, then `bottom: 0` will make it stick to the bottom of the parent element.

Giving the `body` a relative position:

```css
.footer{
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: lightblue;
}
body{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<div class='footer'>FOOTER</div>
```

Creating a wrapper `div`:

```css
.footer{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class='footer'>FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

You can also just use the `footer` tag without giving it a position which will always stay at the bottom of the page.

```css
.footer{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p><p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsem...</p>
<footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
```